.filter() finds record but .get() with same query parameters does not
I am doing an ORM query using the .filter without the timeframe specified which returns two records. then I print those record column values to ensure I am not making any mismatches but then when I use the exact same values on the .GET method I get DoesNotExist error even though it just printed that record.
here is are the prints:
Filter Query: timeframe=H4, symbol=XAUUSD, time=2024-04-10 14:00:00+00:00
Filter Record 2: XAUUSD, 2024-04-10 14:00:00, H4
GET Query: timeframe=H4, symbol=XAUUSD, time=2024-04-10 14:00:00+00:00
No record found.

and the code:
@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def get_label_data(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    data = data.get('data')
    timestamp = data.get('timestamp')
    symbol_name = data.get('symbol')
    label_name_str = data.get('label_name')
    timeframe = data.get('timeframe')

    symbol = Symbol.objects.get(name=symbol_name)
    datetime_stamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=pytz.UTC)

    print(f"Filter Query: timeframe={timeframe}, symbol={symbol_name}, time={datetime_stamp}")
    forex_ohlc = ForexOHLC.objects.filter(symbol=symbol, time=datetime_stamp)
    forex_ohlc = list(forex_ohlc)[1]
    print(f"Filter Record 2: {forex_ohlc.symbol.name}, {forex_ohlc.time}, {timeframe}")

    print(f"GET Query: timeframe={timeframe}, symbol={symbol_name}, time={datetime_stamp}")
    try:
        forex_ohlc = ForexOHLC.objects.get(symbol=symbol, time=datetime_stamp, timeframe=timeframe)
    except ForexOHLC.DoesNotExist:
        print("No record found.")
    except ForexOHLC.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        print("Multiple records found.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

    try:
        labels = TickLabel.objects.get(forex_ohlc=forex_ohlc, symbol=symbol, label_name__name=label_name_str)
        return JsonResponse({
            'label_name': labels.label_name.name,
            'label_type': labels.label_type.name,
            'hasLabel': True
        })
    except TickLabel.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'hasLabel': False})


I think the .filter() and .get() queries that you showed are NOT equal, because the first one uses 2 filter parameters, but in the second query a third parameter is also added (timeframe):
forex_ohlc = ForexOHLC.objects.filter(symbol=symbol, time=datetime_stamp)
forex_ohlc = ForexOHLC.objects.get(symbol=symbol, time=datetime_stamp, timeframe=timeframe)

This could mean that the 2 records found by the filter query have a different value for timeframe than the value H4.
Note that when printing the found records, your code does not actually print forex_ohlc.timeframe but instead it prints only the filter variable timeframe.
print(f"Filter Record 2: {forex_ohlc.symbol.name}, {forex_ohlc.time}, {timeframe}")

